# Neo4j- typical query - returning a node with the most appearances

Tags: neo4j

I have to make a query that returns me a club or clubs, where play the most amount of players that are not representing the country, from where the club is.

My query works fine, but I want to filter, so my result is ONLY clubs that size is the most.

As for now the biggest size is 4, and I have 4 clubs that have 4 players which were supposed to be there.

The only thing comes to my mind to filter it out was by using `LIMIT 1` in the end, but then, I cut out three clubs, that also fill the predicate.

```
MATCH (c: Club)<-[r: PLAYS_FOR]-(p: Player)-[r2: REPRESENTS]->(n: NationalTeam)
WHERE c.country<>n.country
WITH c,collect(p.name) as list_players,n.country as country,size(collect(p.name)) as size
RETURN c,list_players,country,size ORDER BY size DESC LIMIT 1
```

edit:

I managed to do something like this, don't know if it's optimal, but it is working:

```
MATCH (c: Club)<-[r: PLAYS_FOR]-(p: Player)-[r2: REPRESENTS]->(n: NationalTeam)
WHERE c.country<>n.country
WITH c,collect(p.name) as list_players,n.country as country,size(collect(p.name)) as size
WITH c,list_players,country,size ORDER BY size DESC LIMIT 1
WITH size
MATCH (c: Club)<-[r: PLAYS_FOR]-(p: Player)-[r2: REPRESENTS]->(n: NationalTeam)
WHERE c.country<>n.country
WITH size,c,collect(p.name) as list_players,n.country as country,size(collect(p.name)) as size2 WHERE size(collect(p.name)) = size
RETURN c,list_players,country,size
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install APOC Procedures, there is an aggregation function you can use to get the items associated with a maximum value, and this works even when multiple items are tied for that value: `apoc.agg.maxItems()`

The trouble now is that all the club-specific data needs to be encapsulated into the item itself, so you'll need to add them to a map and use the map as the item, and the size of the person collection as the value.

Also your aggregation isn't quite correct. You're collecting player names, but you have the country of the player as a part of the grouping key (when you aggregate, all non-aggregation terms form the grouping key), and that isn't likely want you want. Maybe you wanted the country of the club instead?

Try working from this:

```
MATCH (c: Club)<-[r: PLAYS_FOR]-(p: Player)-[r2: REPRESENTS]->(n: NationalTeam)
WHERE c.country<>n.country
WITH c,collect(p) as list_players
WITH apoc.agg.maxItems({club:c, players:list_players}, size(list_players)) as maxResults
UNWIND maxResults.items as result
WITH result.club as c, [player IN result.players | player.name] as list_players, maxResults.value as size
RETURN c,list_players,size
```